# Derivative of $\sqrt {xy}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\sqrt{|xy|} = 1$

Attempting to find the derivative gives me $$\frac12(xy)^{-1/2}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx} + y\right) = 0$$

But I haven't figured out how to simplify this further. My teacher says that that's all I'll need to know, but I want to understand how the derivative of $\sqrt {xy} = 1$ is $-\frac{y}x$.

Edited to explain that I know the whole thing equals zero, but how do I solve for (dy/dx)?

Attempts to solve get me this far:
[image]

Comment: The expression you found should be set equal to $0$ because you differentiated *both* sides of the equation $\sqrt{xy} = 1$ with respect to $x$.  If you have a product of factors equal to $0$, what can you conclude?

Comment: How is $\sqrt{|z|}=1$ different from $|z|=1$?

Comment: Your subject has $\sqrt{xy}$ while the body of the question has $\sqrt{|xy|}$. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the derivative of the righthand side of $\sqrt{xy}=1$ as well: the derivative of the constant $1$ is $0$, so you get

$$\frac12(xy)^{-1/2}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx} + y\right)=0\;.$$

Now solve this equation for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear, but if $\sqrt{x y}=1$ then $xy=1$, hence $y=x^{-1}$ and $y'=-x^{-2}=-\frac yx=-y^2$.

Comment: You've gotten rid of the absolute value sign how?

Comment: Differentiability is a *local* property. If $x>0$ then $y=y(x)>0$, and if $x<0$ then $y=y(x)<0$. The absolute value is not very important, in this question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I got rid of the absolute value just as the OP did mid-post. And apparently Brian made the same simplification. Actually, from $\sqrt{|xy|}=1$ for some function $y\colon x\mapsto y(x)$ we could not even infer that $y$ is a *continuous* function at all, even less differentiable.

Comment: I like Hagen's solution

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has done it, let me expand on Michael Joyce's comment.  Since

$$\frac12(xy)^{-\frac12}(x\frac{dy}{dx}+y)=0$$

then either

$$(xy)^{-\frac12}=0 \text{ or } x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

But if $(xy)^\frac12=1$, then $(xy)^{-\frac12}=1$.  Therefore, it follows that

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0,\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac yx$$